# Initial window size when using a QScrollArea within QSplitter slightly too small making scrollbars show up

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a Qt (5.8 C++) window that contains a horizontal QSplitter.  Initially I simply contained 2 widgets (not QScrollArea's) and my main window would initialize to the minimum size of each internal widget (about 500x600) and the splitter wouldn't really slide anywhere unless I grew the window because the components were already at minimum size.  But it looked good.

However, since I know the top widget can sometimes grow to be quite large in typical use, I put it inside a QScrollArea and put THAT into the top half of the QSplitter instead.  I expected it to initialize to about 500x600 just like before (with NO scrollbars) and for the scroll bars to only appear if I shrunk the window (or grew the internal widget afterwards).  But what appears to happen is that the QScrollArea wants to draw a skinny border around the component it is containing.  This adds a few pixels to the minimum size required to display my entire widget causing it to always start out drawing scroll bars.  If I use the mouse to grow the height of the window by a couple pixels, the scroll bar goes away.  So every time I run my application, my first step is to grow the height of my window by a few pixels to get the annoying scroll bars to go away.  Perhaps QScrollBar doesn't add those pixels for the border to the height of the minimum size?   (I did try to add a few pixels to the minimum size and it seems to have no effect).

Is there a way to make my window initialize to have no scroll bars if the widget size were small enough for the window to be smaller than full screen?  I only want scrollbars to appear if they are necessary.

Hopefully, the following sample code helps to explain what I did to get here:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    auto centralSplitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);
    setCentralWidget(centralSplitter);

    auto button1 = new QPushButton("Top\nButton\n(Add more lines of text than this to make button taller)");

    //This looks fine, but has no scroll bar
    //centralSplitter->addWidget(button1); 

    // This creates a scroll bar even if it shouldn't be necessary 
    auto scrollArea1 = new QScrollArea;  
    scrollArea1->setWidget(button1);
    centralSplitter->addWidget(scrollArea1);


    auto button2 = new QPushButton("Bottom\nButton\n(I also added more text here too)");
    centralSplitter->addWidget(button2);
}
```

Comment: You could show what you get and indicate the error or inconvenience you have.

Comment: I added more text to make it more clear.  I hope that helps.

Comment: An image would be much better.

Comment: I do not get the scroll bars at first, they appear only when I reduce the size.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm at work now.  I will have to try to provide an image when I get back home.  I didn't realize that we could include images... I am running on Qt 5.8 on Linux.  Are you using Windows or other OS?  Perhaps you can try to make the button's larger in your test?  I used something like "A\nA\n......" probably 10-15 times to make them taller.  I didn't paste that because I didn't think that would matter.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution.  It doesn't seem ideal but I created my own subclass of QScrollArea and overloaded sizeHint() to add 6 pixels to both width and height to the widget it contains.  (I arrived at 6 through trial and error).

```
class MyScrollArea: public QScrollArea {
public:
    virtual QSize sizeHint() const;
};

QSize MyScrollArea::sizeHint() const {
    auto widgetSize = widget()->sizeHint();
    return QSize(widgetSize.width()+6,widgetSize.height()+6);
}
```

Now the window initializes without any scroll bars like I expected it to before.